# How to change http req header for @Component call to templateUrl?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an angular2 component declared like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard-subpage',
  templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard',
})

export class DashboardComponent {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

and the endpoint templates/dashboard returns different html according to current lang and authorization state, which browser holds in localstorage.

So does any anyone please have an idea, how to add Authoriation and Accept-Language header to this http request. I found solution requiring rewriting of core libs ([Angular2 default http headers with templateURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628403/angular2-default-http-headers-with-templateurl)). But as I intend to upgrade my angular version later on, i prefere not to do this.

My current version is 2.4.0.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think this explicitly not supported because it would create apps that fundamentally incompatible with AoT, and the Angular team tends not to do that.  Angular encourages you to do a build for each supported language instead of run-time translation.

Comment: After the build temllate became inline automatically so in production mode there is no calls fot templates